# How does one purge a database of old revisions?

Tags: wagtail

How might I remove old revisions from the Wagtail database?  I see that every time I make a change the previous revision of the page is kept in the database ... very nice, but how do I "take out the trash?"

In other words: *"okay, this page is now finished, and I don't wish to keep previous revisions of it anymore."*  You'd think this would be easy – but, where is it?

Answer (score 7):

Revisions are stored in the `wagtail.core.models.PageRevision` model, which is the `wagtailcore_pagerevision` table in the database. To delete all revisions for a given page, you can run the following from `./manage.py shell`:

```
from wagtail.core.models import PageRevision
PageRevision.objects.filter(page_id=123).delete()
```

Note that the 'save as draft' and 'submit for moderation' workflows also work by saving PageRevision entries, so you should only do this after the page has been published in the state that you want to keep.

Comment: "Well, that may be so," but I think that it's an obvious candidate for a user-interface feature and/or a management command.  :-)  I'll make that suggestion somewhere.  This should be "easy peasy."

Comment: For instance, could I use an SQLite shell to simply say:  `DELETE FROM wagtailcore_pagerevision; VACUUM` ...?   Would I irrevocably break anything?

Comment: ***Eeek!***  I see that this simple-minded approach would _not_ work, because the `wagtailcore_page` table contains a column,`live_revision_id`.  So, revisions that are pointed-to by this table must not be removed.  (And I don't think that SQLite can support a `DELETE` query to do this in one step.)

Comment: gasman, are you _sure_ that your answer would work, given this fact?  Would it not also delete the "live" revision ...?

Comment: The live page content is always available in the tables corresponding to the actual page models, rather than the page revisions table - that way you can write the "obvious" queries for listing pages and the like, and be assured of getting back live content. In normal circumstances there will _also_ be a corresponding record in the page revisions table, which is what `live_revision_id` points to, but this isn't really used for anything other than indicating the current live version in Wagtail's revision listing view. The Wagtail admin will gracefully handle the absence of revision records.

Comment: Uh huh, so you say ... but I don't see text in the `wagtailcore_page` table.  I do see it in `home_homepage`.  I'm still nervous ...

Comment: Yes - Wagtail pages use multi-table inheritance (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), meaning that for each page model, the data is split between `wagtailcore_page` (containing the fields common to all page types, such as title) and the page model's own table such as `home_homepage` (containing the fields specific to that model). If you're still not convinced, by all means make a database backup before trying it out!

Comment: As I suspected, emptying the `wagtailcore_pagerevisions` table caused a runtime error when attempting to save a revision ... not of a *new* page, but of an *existing* one.  (I did not attempt anything more draconian, such as setting the pointer in `wagtailcore_page` to NULL.  Instead, I restored the database file from a backup.)

Answer (score 0):

Since Wagtail 2.10 there exists a management command which should purge revisions (purges old revisions, keep the latest revision):

```bash
$ ./manage.py purge_revisions --help
usage: manage.py purge_revisions [-h] [--days DAYS] [--pages] [--non-pages]
[...]
Delete revisions which are not the latest revision, published or scheduled to
be published, or in moderation

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --days DAYS           Only delete revisions older than this number of days
  --pages               Only delete revisions of page models
  --non-pages           Only delete revisions of non-page models
  [...]

$ ./manage.py purge_revisions
Successfully deleted 109628 revisions
```

After purging old revisions with this management command the database (in my case it was SQlite) could be vacuumed to reflect the deletions and compact/shrink the database:

```bash
$ sqlite3 <sqlite-db-file> "VACUUM;"
```